# Arduino код для измерение влажности и температуры вывода их на LCD дисплей

Tags: c++, c, инспекция-кода, arduino

Можно ли улучшить код?

Если кратко то код для измерение влажности и температуры вывода их на LCD дисплей и в случае если температура огромная или маленькая то включается одно из реле.

Весь код:

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h> // библиотека для управления устройствами по I2C 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> // подключаем библиотеку для QAPASS 1602

#define DHTTYPE DHT22

#define DHTPIN 3
#define relayPin_warm 2
#define relayPin_cold 11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

float hum;
float temp;
byte temp_status = 0;
unsigned long timer = 0;

/*
 start - temp_status = 0
 too cold - temp_status = 1
 too warm - temp_status = 2
 */

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);


void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   
   pinMode(relayPin_warm, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(relayPin_cold, OUTPUT);

   dht.begin();   
   
   lcd.begin(16, 2);
}


void loop(){  
    if (millis() - timer > 1000) {
        timer = millis();
        hum = dht.readHumidity();
        temp = dht.readTemperature();
        
        if (temp < 18) {
            if (temp_status != 1) {
                if (temp_status == 2) {
                    digitalWrite(relayPin_warm, LOW); // disable warm relay
                }
            
                digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, HIGH); // enable cold relay
                temp_status = 1;   
            }
        }
        else if (temp > 21) {
            if (temp_status != 2) {
                if (temp_status == 1) {
                    digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, LOW); // disable cold relay      
                } 
                digitalWrite(relayPin_warm, HIGH); // enable warm relay
                temp_status = 2;  
            }
        }
        else {
            if (temp_status == 1) {
                digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, LOW); // disable cold relay
            }
            else if (temp_status == 2) {
                digitalWrite(relayPin_warm, LOW); // disable warm relay
            }
            temp_status = 0;
        }

        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);           //
        lcd.print("TEMP: ");   // 
        lcd.print(temp);       //
        lcd.print('C');        // working with 
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);   // lcd dispaly 
        lcd.print("HUM: ");    //
        lcd.print(hum);        //
        lcd.print('%');        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, стоит избавиться от магических чисел. Еще почитайте про енумераторы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повторная запись одного и того же значения на выходной пин не имеет отрицательных последствий - с точки зрения устройства, подключенного к этому пину, ничего не произошло. Поэтому можно избавиться от переменной temp_status:

```
// ...
temp = dht.readTemperature();

digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, (temp < 18 ? HIGH : LOW));
digitalWrite(relayPin_warm, (temp > 21 ? HIGH : LOW));

lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
// ...
```

Comment: ¿Интересно, а не будет ли проблемой  одновременная подача сигнала на оба выхода?

Comment: Спасибо! С вашей помощью узнал и  изучил про краткие конструкции if else

Comment: Предложенный код работает точно так же, как и ваш. Оба варианта имеют весьма существенный недостаток. Если температура близка к граничному значению и колеблется вокруг него, реле может много раз включаться и выключаться.

Comment: Можно использовать простое решение. Например,заменить строку `digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, (temp < 18 ? HIGH : LOW));` на `if (temp < 17.5) digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, HIGH);  if (temp > 18.5) digitalWrite(relayPin_cold, LOW);` Допуск 0.5 взят произвольно.  Так же для второго реле.